# What's the difference between Model.query and session.query(Model) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm a beginner in SQLAlchemy and found query can be done in 2 method:

Approach 1:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
class _Base(object):
    query = DBSession.query_property()

Base = declarative_base(cls=_Base)

class SomeModel(Base):
    key   = Column(Unicode, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Unicode)

# When querying
result = SomeModel.query.filter(...)
```

Approach 2

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Base = declarative_base()

class SomeModel(Base):
    key   = Column(Unicode, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Unicode)

# When querying
session = DBSession()
result = session.query(SomeModel).filter(...)
```

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 21):

In the code above, there is no difference. This is because, in line 3 of the first example:

- the `query` property is explicitly bound to `DBSession`
- there is no custom `Query` object passed to `query_property`

As @petr-viktorin points out in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14553324/1648762), there must be a session available before you define your model in the first example, which might be problematic depending on the structure of your application.

If, however, you need a custom query that adds additional query parameters automatically to all queries, then only the first example will allow that. A custom query class that inherits from `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query` can be passed as an argument to `query_property`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920724/the-right-way-to-auto-filter-sqlalchemy-queries) shows an example of that pattern.

Even if a model object has a custom query property defined on it, that property is not used when querying with `session.query`, as in the last line in the second example. This means something like the first example the only option if you need a custom query class.

Answer (score 7):

I see these downsides to [`query_property`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.query_property):

- You cannot use it on a different Session than the one you've configured (though you could always use `session.query` then).
- You need a session object available before you define your schema.

These could bite you when you want to write tests, for example.

Also, `session.query` fits better with how SQLAlchemy works; `query_property` looks like it's just added on top for convenience (or similarity with other systems?).
I'd recommend you stick to `session.query`.

Comment: I just got bittten. This comment was right

Answer (score 6):

An answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11557211/1243435)) to a different SQLAlchemy question might help. That answer starts with:

> You can use `Model.query`, because the `Model` (or usually its base class, especially in cases where declarative extension is used) is assigned `Session.query_property`. In this case the `Model.query` is equivalent to `Session.query(Model)`.